# Lines or streaks when Applying Textures

Tags: texturing, uv

I created a cube and I added  a simple texture to it. On some faces of the cube, the texture is skewed and this produces some strange lines on some of the faces of the cube.
And I don't think it's about how I unwrapped the cube because even if I set the Texture Cordinate Node to Generate, those lines still persist.[image: I hope you can see what I am talking about.]
Can anyone help me solve it?

Comment: Don't use generated coordinates, use UV coordinates.

Comment: Take a few minutes to watch https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=265 and understand how to use texture coordinates.

Comment: yes please, I will..

Answer (score 1):

This effect is produced by having faces unwrapped as lines in the UV coordinates. Meaning, your long rectangles are represented as long lines in the UV layout, without any width to them. So the pixels of the texture are correctly represented only in 1 dimension (ALONG the rectangle), but not in the other.